# How do I add various document types to a Firebird BLOB field with Delphi

Tags: delphi, blob, firebird, document

**Background**: Our product includes a document management system that allows users to save and retrieve various document types (.PDF, .DOC, .JPG, .PNG, .TIF, etc.). Currently there is a record in the database that stores document information, but the documents themselves are stored on the server's hard drive. The database record includes the disk file name so it can be retrieved and displayed. We now need to migrate all the documents into the database. For some of our clients, that could mean thousands of individual document files.  We are aware of the pros and cons of having the docs in the DB, but still need to migrate them to the DB.

**The plan**: I plan to loop through the table containing all the document information. Each record now has a new, empty BLOB field, and a text field to hold the file extension (so that I know how to display it later). The plan is to retrieve the file and save it in the new BLOB field, along with its extension, as I loop to the next record/document.

**Question**: The articles I've read so far use Streams to create a totally new record. The type of stream depends on the article (TMemoryStream, TFileStream, TBlobStream). Since I already have a record, I'm interested in knowing the best way to fill the BLOB field. I would appreciate it if someone can offer an example of Delphi code that would add such a document to a Firebird database. I've been coding for too many years to count, but have never had the opportunity to work with BLOB streams.

Comment: Don't trust "_the file extension_" - often enough people misname files as f.e. `.png` when they're in fact JFIF (`.jpg`) and vice versa. At least check the first bytes of each file for [known signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) and then assume their format.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your DataSet's [`CreateBlobStream()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.CreateBlobStream) method to access a BLOB field of an existing record.  You can write whatever you want to that stream.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through your Query:
`Query.close;`
`Query.sql.text := 'select * from ATable';`
`Query.open;`
`While not Query.eof do`
`Begin`
`if FileExists(Query.FieldbyName('DocumentName').asstring) then`
`Begin`
`Query.Edit;`
`TBlobField(Query.Fieldbyname('Document').LoadFromFile(`
`Query.FieldbyName('DocumentName).asstring);`
`Query.post;`
`end;`
`Query.next;`
`end;`

Comment: Please use [proper formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and not HTML - as you can see (and should have noticed with the preview) your code renders unindented and without syntax highlighting.

Comment: Also, consider saving the queried filename to a local variable so you are not reading it twice from the DB. You should also wrap the loading in a `try..except` so you can abort the edit if an error occurs.